# Configure path to images in CSS for dev and production environments

Tags: css, url, static, hosting

I'm currently developing a website and I have my local environment which is hosted on an XP box with IIS 5.1. I'm using ASP MVC2 and .NET Framework 4.0.

What I want to know is, if there's a way to "configure" in web.config (or any other ways) a path for all my images so that when my CSS uses url() it automatically knows where to look for.

The main reason behind this is that we have a lot of images and documents that we do not want to store in our source control as it's not relevant to have them in there since it changes a lot from our content writers.

Providing a dev and prod space for them to edit, review and deploy their own documents is also a huge benefit for productivity and I want to keep it that way if possible as we have a mechanism to validate that all the files linked in our sites are valid.

So, for example, on my dev box, I would like to use "http://static.devserver/Images/..." but when deploying, I would like them to use "http://static.productionserver/Images/..."

Obviously, considering my requirements above, hosting the CSS on the static subdomain wouldn't be working out in this scenario or maybe I've missed something?

I've been told to use mod_rewrite and/or htaccess but I'm not very well documented on this and seems rather complex for the time I have right now to deliver this project.

All in all, I'd like you guys out there to share your thoughts and suggestions on ways I could get this working as I described it above.

Thanks a lot for reading!

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy solution to do exactly what you want.
You might have to output .css file as a dynamic page, substituting a string from configuration before each URL( in CSS.

Do you really need a subdomain? Why not use a subfolder? url('/css/yourcss.css') is universal for both dev and production.

(Well, I know there are issues with additional traffic from cookies, but still, this is WAAAY easier to do)

Comment: My problem is, I don't want the content to be part of the host application. 

Content "should" be hosted on it's own domain: 

For dev: 

Application => www.MyApp.dev (resides on server A) 

Content => www.static.MyApp.dev (resides on server B) 

For Production: 

Application => www.MyApp.com (resides on server C) 

Content => www.static.MyApp.com (resides on server D) 

Maybe I'm over-complicating everything but those are the requirements I've been given...

Answer (score 0):

BarMonster's relative path is the way to go. The url('/subfolder/yourfile.ext'). That's the best way to do images, and most links within the site to be able to translate between test and live environments.

Comment: yes, I understand that but, that's in the case the content is served under the same physical location the CSS files are...
My requirements are that the web site has to be deployed to web server A but the content resides on server B on a web server hosting static content. 
The only way right now would be to host the CSS files on server B so that the images or any other content would be relative to the css files but that's not a solution since I would have to deploy my css files separately and move them out of the project and would cause a bit of pain for the source control as well...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot guys for trying to help me out!
I finally digged again in url rewriting to find the solution to my problem!
I needed to "redirect" instead of "rewriting" the url!

Now it works as intended!

I'm using Intelligencia's URL Rewriter with this simple rule:

```
<rewriter>
        <redirect url="^.+\.(?:jpg|bmp|png|gif)$" to="http://myDEVserver$0" processing="stop" />
</rewriter>
```

Comment: Sorry to disappoint you, but this sucks :-)
Every request to any static file would cause an additional request on your app server. This is rather slow.

The only correct solution is to put final URLs right inside your CSS files. This might be done dynamically, or statically using some template tools.

Comment: So, do you have any pointers to do it dynamically or statically?

Answer (score 0):

I realize this question went cold along time ago, but it's the first result for my search in google, so I thought I'd take a stab at it in case it helps others.

My solution to this problem is to move all the rules within my CSS files which contain url() statements to my View.

I am using Razor in MVC 3, so I include a style section in my base layout file, and put all the troublesome url rules in there.  Then I can use the MVC engine to determine the appropriate url at runtime. You could modify this to dynamically look at a different domain as well.

```
<style type="text/css">
    .back
    {
        background: url(@Url.Content("~/Content/icons/gray/back.png")) no-repeat;
    }
    .link
    {
        background: url(@Url.Content("~/Content/icons/gray/link.png")) no-repeat;
    }
</style>
```

The syntax is for the Razor engine, but for MVC 2 you could do the same thing within your MasterPage.